# Problem in saving aspx file with encoding

Tags: visual-studio, multilingual, arabic

I am developing a web application in Arabic. For that I convert existing pages in English to Arabic and save the file with encoding.

But when I restarted Visual Studio all the arabic characters are changed to '?'.

What might have caused this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be an issue of character-encoding.

You can try adding this to your header:

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">

or set your document encoding to 8859-6

Comment: Where can I set the encoding for a document?

Comment: Isn't `charset=utf-8` usually better?

Comment: Utf-8 is optimised for Western European languages; Cp 1256 or ISO-8859-6 are Arabic character sets.  If the OP wants an Arabic app & is not concerned about localization they may be a better choice.

Comment: ISO 8859-6 is specifically designed for Arabic encoding. (http://www.unicodetools.com/unicode/codepages.php?codepage=iso-8859-6). You can find more information on ISO 8859 charsets here: http://czyborra.com/charsets/iso8859.html
Maybe other readers can contribute on the difference of using ISO 8859-6 and UTF-8

Comment: Nobodt uses ISO 8859-6, I'd say most (95%) of the electronic content in Arabic is encoded MS CP 1256.